# Adicionar dispositivos ao Quartus II 13.0sp1 usando arquivo .qdz

Tags: intel

Aconteceu comigo e tive certa dificuldade em encontrar a solução, então resolvi compartilhá-la.

O problema ocorre quando o Quartus indica que não há dispositivos instalados e, ao acessar o `Install Devices` na interface, nada acontece. Infelizmente não tenho prints agora que já resolvi o problema, mas quem estiver passando por isso se identificará.

Como resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O primeiro passo é acessar a [central de downloads](https://dl.altera.com/13.0sp1/) do site da Altera para a versão 13.0sp1*, e baixar o arquivo correspondente ao dispositivo desejado. No meu caso, foi o da família Cyclone II. Talvez seja necessário criar uma conta gratuita no site para realizar o download.

[image: Central de downloads do site da Altera]

Após baixar, mova o arquivo (de extensão .qdz) para um diretório conhecido, que será usado a seguir.

Em seguida, busque pelo Quartus II 13.0sp1 Device Installer e execute-o.

[image: Device Installer]

Após clicar em next na primeira janela, selecione o diretório que contém o arquivo .qdz e avance.

[image: Selecionando diretório do arquivo]

**Provavelmente você receberá um erro** dizendo que o diretório selecionado não possui arquivos qdz, então renomeie o arquivo qdz seguindo um dos seguintes padrões: `cycloneV-13.1.0.162.qdz` ou `cyclone_web-13.1.0.162.qdz`. A alteração é basicamente em um _ ou - mas agora voltando à seleção do diretório, funcionará.

Após o arquivo ser selecionado, basta avançar na instalação e concluir. Após isso o dispositivo instalado estará disponível no Quartus.

*Se alguém testar em outras versões e funcionar, favor editar a resposta adicionando essa informação.